# Get row null from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I try to debug, I see that my button is null. Anyone knows why? Here's the code. Thanks in advance!

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    Label headerAthleteID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblAthleteID");
    con.Close();
}
```

Here's my grid view part

```
         <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="deleteColumn">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID ="deleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="Delete_Click" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What do you mean "I see that my button is null"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Your code works just fine. I get the Button in `Delete_Click`.